# What role do semiclassical methods play in the study of Ginzburg--Landau-type equations?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde, geometric-analysis, micro-local-analysis

As far as I understand, semiclassical limits are used in quantum mechanics to analyse equations that depend on a small parameter $\hbar$. Apparently studying properties of the PDE as $\hbar \to 0$ should capture some behaviour that occurs between the 'macroscopic' classical scale and 'microscopic' quantum scale.

A famous PDE that depends on a small parameter $\epsilon > 0$ is the *Ginzburg–Landau equation*:
\begin{equation}
\epsilon \Delta u + \epsilon^{-1} u ( 1 - \lvert u \rvert^2) = 0,
\end{equation}
defined for $\mathbf{C}$-valued functions $u$. Here one often considers sequences of solutions $(u_{\epsilon_j} \mid j \in \mathbf{N})$ along some sequence $\epsilon_j \to 0$. In the limit as $j \to \infty$ the $u_{\epsilon_j}$ converge weakly away from a codimension two set where the energies concentrate and vortices appear.

**Question.** Do semiclassical methods play a role in thes analysis of this PDE? In theory, what sort of mathematical questions could be approached from this 'quantum' point of view?

Comment: Maybe the other direction is also interesting: is varifold convergence etc. in geometric measure theory useful in semiclassical analysis?

Comment: @KeleiWang That may be; I hadn't considered that! Unfortunately I know too little of this semiclassical world to tell whether these are sensible questions...